# CSS: Clearfix Background image not working

Tags: css

I have search other questions on this subject, but could not find anything that was a match.
I have 3 pictures in my index.html that show just fine, but I an having trouble with having a background jpg showing.

```
 <div class="cf">
    <div class="box">
        <a href="">
            <img src="images/pizza.jpg"/>
            <p>Vegetarian</p>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <a href="">
            <img src="images/pasta.jpg"/>
            <p>5 Minuts Meals</p>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <a href="">
            <img src="images/diet.jpg"/>
            <p>Diet Recipes</p>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### style.css

```
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}

#main {
    background-image: url("images/dishes.jpg");
    height: 438px;
}
```

Comment: This is not all your HTML right? There should be an element with `id="main"`.

Comment: correct.    <div id="main">
  <p>Join our E-mail club</p>
  <p>Sign up now!</p>
  <form>
   <input id="email" type="email" placeholder=" enter your email">
   <input id="click" type="submit" value="CLICK HERE">
  </form>
 </div>

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this, so it is universal.

```
*{
 background-image: url("images/dishes.jpg");
}
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: Using the * blows everything out of proportion.

Comment: Then adjust everything to its position. @Chazz other than that i cant tell you anything. Sorry i cant help :-(

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there was an issue with the file extension in the css folder.
Once I took out the style-sheet from the css folder it worked fine.